# Linq query on EFCore Sqlite does not work

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core, system.data.sqlite

I'm using EFCore SQLite, when run a simple query with Linq, I notice that the query `Take().Last()` does not return what is expected, sample code:

```
// There are more than 10000 rows in the table
DbSet<DataEntry> set = ctx.Set<DataEntry>();
// this should return the first 20 rows
var current = set.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Take(20);
// first entry is right
long tStart = current.First().Time;
// This should have returned the last entry in the first 20 entries, but instead, it returned the last entry of the entire data set
long tEnd = current.Last().Time;

// so essentially it looks like this:
set.Last().Time == set.Take(20).Last().Time
```

It looks `Last` will return the last entry in the entire backing data set, no matter which query it is based on. How can I fix this?

Comment: call `ToList` on `current` before grabbing first and last. ie `var current = set.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Take(20).ToList()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested and reproduced in EF Core 2.0.1, SqlServer, hence this seems to be a current EF Core bug in `Last` / `LastOrDefault` general query translation.

The query

```
var last = set.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Take(20).Last();
```

is translated as if it was

```
var last = set.OrderByDescending(row => row.Id).Take(20).First();
```

which of course is not equivalent and always returns the last record of the whole sequence (`Take` has no effect).

I would suggest reporting it to the EF Core [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues).

Meanwhile, as a workaround you could use the ugly explicit equivalent:

```
var last = set.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Take(20)
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.Id).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `ToList` on `current` before grabbing first and last?

```
//...code removed for brevity.

var current = set.OrderBy(row => row.Id).Take(20).ToList();

//...code removed for brevity.
```

Comment: Why is that? when the back db is sqlserver, last works as expected even on a query.

Comment: Not all providers are the same. It could be a bug with the query provider.

Comment: @fluter I would also suggest you look at the query that was generated for `Take` and make sure it uses the correct syntax.